# Simple object manipuation of javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
function abc(req, res, next) {
  let imageName = req.body.name;
   const obj = {
    imageName: {
      status: true,
      url: "abc"
    }
 }
```

In above function I have a varaible declared 'imageName'. I just need to use result that is got at 'imageName' variable at 'obj'. suppose I get 'alpha' from req.body.name then I want to use that in 'obj' like `obj = {aplha: {status: true, url: "abc"} }`.

Comment: You can do  `let obj = {}` and `obj[req.body.name] =  { status: true, url: "abc" }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/using-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) to provide a dynamic key to an object.

```js
let imageName = 'alpha';
const obj = {
  [imageName]: {
    status: true,
    url: "abc"
  }
}
console.log(obj);
```

Your code will be

```js
function abc(req, res, next) {
  let imageName = req.body.name;
   const obj = {
    [imageName]: {
      status: true,
      url: "abc"
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your question right, you need to use the bracket notation with the object to get a dynamic key value:

```
function abc(req, res, next) {
    const obj = {};
    obj[req.body.name] = {status: true, url: "abc"};
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

On a side note, you can still reference the value later using the dot notation later on . . . for example, if you want to later check to see if "obj" has an "alpha" value, you can do it with either `if (obj.alpha . . .` or `if {obj[alpha] . . .)`, but only the bracket notation approach will work when using a dynamic, variable-based key (e.g., `if (obj[req.body.name] . . .)`).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question right you want to update the obj object? do like so

```
obj['newKey'] = { status: true, url: "abc" }
```

Answer (score 0):

While I cannot find the appropriate use case for this, you could always store the value in `req.body.name` and use that as a key in your obj like so:

```
function abc(req, res, next) {
   let imageName = req.body.name;
   const obj = {}
   obj[imageName] = {
      status: true,
      url: "abc"
    }
 }
```